# Can't deploy from IntelliJ to SF one component, but the controller is ok

Tags: apex, deployment, intellij

I'm using IntelliJ Idea, retrieving datas from SF each day ;
But now I got this error :

**Deployment Failed: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - Invalid definition for null:LTNG01_SearchCandidate: Variable does not exist: Alias: Source**

What is to understand ??
Because I still CAN save the controller (LTNG01_SearchCandidate) :

This is the header of the component I can't save :
[image]

And the Controller (that I still can save) :
[image]

What is to understand about this alias thing ?

This is the deployments I tried / achieve :

[image]

Thanks for your time / help,
If it persist I'll delete and retrieve the all datas ...

Comment: It sounds like a code error somewhere in your Aura component. there a variable somewhere in your Aura component called Alias or Source, or a reference to such a variable somewhere in the JS? When deploying an AuraDefinitionBundle, the IDE deploys all the elements - component, JS controller, JS helper, etc. So it could be in any of those.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm back to work so I'll try what you''ve explained. Just refreshed from the serveur, the error still persists ; what I can't understand is that it means from the Dev Console I was able to save with an error ? - I'm trying some Notepad++ Compare on files I'm curious.

Comment: So obviously, when recovering from server I don't have errors anymore. But still, don't really understand what happened. Let's say a did a mistake somewhere ! Thanks again